# How to dynamically create mapped type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Given:

```
type Indexed<Key extends number, Value> {
    [key in Key]: Value
}

let objLiteral: Indexed<1 | 2, string> = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
}
```

Now I want to dynamically create a new `Indexed<1 | 2, {x: string}>`. The equivalent JavaScript should be correct, but this doesn't compile:

```
let mappedObj: Indexed<1 | 2, {x: string}> =
    Object.keys(objLiteral).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = {x: objLiteral[cur]}
        return acc
    }, {})
```

Now, it works just fine if I add `as Indexed<1 | 2, { x: string }>` to the end of it. But that's basically just telling the compiler "trust me, it's correct". Is there a way to do this that doesn't require overriding the type system this way?

Comment: Nope, type assertions are necessary here

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function to do that, but you can create a utility function that has a couple of casts inside, but then will provide you correct types for any usages:

```
function mapObject<
    TObject extends {},
    TItem,
    TKey extends keyof TObject = keyof TObject
>(
    obj: TObject,
    callback: (value: TObject[TKey], key: TKey, obj: TObject) => TItem
): { [K in TKey]: TItem }
{
    const result = {} as { [K in TKey]: TItem }
    for (let key in obj) {
        const k = key as any as TKey
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[k] = callback(obj[k], k, obj)
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let mappedObj = mapObject(objLiteral, x => ({ x }));
mappedObj[1].x; // has type "string" as expected
```